# Recursion in Javascript strange behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find the answer to this question why does this code:

```
    (function h(){
        var x = 1;
        return x;
        x = 2;
    })();
```

Returns 1, when this code:

```
    (function g(){
        function g(){ return 1; }
        return g();
        function g(){ return 2; }
    })();
```

Returns 2

I've debugged it and in both cases in never goes past return g() or return x part. 
The recursion part in function g, should call function g() with the first implementation of it in which it returns 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Javascript hoists (brings to the top) any function definition. The interpreter re-orders your outer function as:

```
(function g(){
    function g(){ return 1; }
    function g(){ return 2; }
    return g();
})();
```

The second g() overrides the first one, and so outer function returns the result of executing that second g(), which is 2.

More about hoisting can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

To get the result you were expecting, you can assign the functions as vars instead, this will not hoist them:

```
(function g(){
    var g = function(){ return 1; }
    return g();
    g = function(){ return 2; }
})()
```

Answer (score 3):

That is called [Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp):

> Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving all declarations
>   to the top of the current scope (to the top of the current script or
>   the current function).

You should be careful with this and, by extension, with any *magic* that JS does when it tries to help you because you weren't disciplined.